# Initializing view binding with requireView()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

Lately I have become fond of initializing my view bindings lazily using `requireView()`.

To elaborate, I tend to write this:

```kotlin
class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {
    
    private val binding by lazy { FragmentExampleBinding.bind(requireView()) }
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // make use of binding
    }

}
```

... instead of this:

```kotlin
class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {
    
    private lateinint var binding: FragmentExampleBinding
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding = FragmentExampleBinding.bind(view)

        // make use of binding
    }

}
```

It feels to me a bit cleaner (although it just saves one or two lines). However, I haven't seen this being used anywhere, which makes come to the actual question:
Is there something wrong with this approach? Is there anything I have overlooked?

**Note:** I can see that making use of `binding` for the first time in ie. a coroutine might cause `requireView()` to be called after the fragment has been killed (and thus throw an `IllegalStateException`). It doesn't seem too concerning to me though, as all coroutines for the fragment should be called "under" its `viewLifecycleOwner` and therefore shouldn't outlive it.

Comment: are you clearing out your bindings with either of these approaches ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Huh, good point. As you can tell, I often don't bother. Just realised that my approach makes it impossible to clear the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your examples technically leak your views when the Fragment's view is destroyed. If you don't care about that, your version of doing it is no worse than using `lateinit`, aside from some insignificant overhead from the property delegate and Lazy's default thread-safety mode.

[Some argue (see onDestroyView section)](https://www.techyourchance.com/android-fragment-lifecycle/) that it doesn't matter if you leak views from a Fragment, because the Fragment instance lives in a destroyed state only temporarily. For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65295104/android-view-binding-clear-binding-in-fragment-lifecycle/65295250).

In practice, I never need to use the binding outside `onViewCreated` anyway, so I just use a local variable instead of a property.